# Android studio 4.1 : Internal Error when trying to start Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio-4.1

I'm sharing this with you :

[image: The error :]

To solve this error : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TBX-5051

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add in `C:/Program-files/Android-studio/bin/idea.properties`

```
disable.android.first.run=true
```

Comment: What's the matter ?

Comment: The solution is on the post. Click on the link